# CoreData Serious application error with inserting new entity

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I have the following code:

```
private lazy var fetchedResultsController: FetchedResultsController<Worker> = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Worker.entityName)
    let workerTypeSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "workerType", ascending: true)
    let firstNameSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
    let lastNameSortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [workerTypeSortDescriptor, firstNameSortDescriptor, lastNameSortDescriptor]

    let context = CoreDataStackSingleton.sharedInstance.managedObjectContext
    let frc = FetchedResultsController<Worker>(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "workerType")
    frc.setDelegate(self.frcDelegate)
    return frc
}()
```

If my table is empty I add director (workerType = 0)person and all is Ok. Then i add employee (workerType = 1)or bookkeeper (workerType = 2) person. And then i get this error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (**0 inserted, 0 deleted**) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (**0 moved in, 0 moved out**). with userInfo (null)

it turns out that a new person is added to the already existing section, but the new section should be created for this.
Here is my project: [link](https://github.com/andertsk/PersonalContacts)

Comment: Its dirty read situation of database table you trying to modify your table more than 2 times before one transaction not completed.

Comment: @Tirth how to catch transaction completion?

Comment: Hi @Andrey M. , listen as Tirth says , check / debug your code properly from where the table getting modified before the transaction not completed.

Comment: @iShwar please see my project. Its all clear that between transactions no modification of table is occured.

Comment: @AndreyM. Did you get any solution for this problem? I'm also facing the same.